# Cómo ejecutar una operación un día determinado en Google Sheets

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

no sé cómo implementar una función en Google Sheets, que llegado un determinado día del mes, siempre el mismo, se ejecute una operación aritmética. Por decir, quiero que el 16 de cada mes, en la celda c12 se ejecute la operacion 10/d12. Es decir, dividir el número 10 entre el valor que tenga la celda d12 en ese momento.

Comment: [¿Qué has intentado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Necesitarás programar un Trigger para ello. [En la documentación](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en#managing_triggers_programmatically) tienes varios ejemplos del tipo: *ejecutar tal bloque de código cada X tiempo*, basta con indicar en el código lo que quieres hacer, en tu caso, ejecutar la operación aritmética a la que haces referencia en la pregunta.

Comment: La verdad es que no sabía por dónde ir, mis conocimeintos del lenguaje Java son MUY limitados. Voy a intentar seguir la recomendación de A. Cedano. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es crear una funcion que valide la fecha que requeris.. en este caso si va ser siempre los dias 16 de cada mes.

```
function EjecutarDiaDeterminado(){
  //Obtengo la fecha de hoy
  let fechaHoy = new Date();
  //Obtengo el numero de dia desde la fecha de hoy
  let dia = fechaHoy.getDate();
  //Compruebo si es el dia que necesito
  if(dia === 16){
    //Realiza la operacion que necesites... si no cumple la condicion.. no realiza nada   
    console.log(dia)
  }  
}
```

La almacenas en la pestaña "Codigo.gs" y luego vas a los "Activadores" y agregas esa función para que se ejecute con frecuencia "DIARIA".

El activador te permite definir un Rango horario en cual se va ejecutar la función, en este caso entre las 00:00 y 01:00 se va ejecutar la función en cuestión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva, Saludos.